# Using Django to build a template on Pydev in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, django-templates

I am attempting to use the template library Django on eclipse. SO far I downloaded the Django-1.7.tar.gz and unzipped it. Then from eclipse I placed it as an external library so that I could import the module. And I can import the module leave it unused and compile my code no problem. However when I call template() I have issues.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from django.template import Template, Context

t=Template("My name is {{my_name}}.")

c=Context({"my_name":"Adrian"})
t.render(c)
```

Output error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\212412120\workspace\protype_1\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    t=Template("My name is {{my_name}}.")

  File "C:\Users\212412120\Downloads\Django-1.7\Django-    1.7\django\template\base.py", line 130, in __init__
    if settings.TEMPLATE_DEBUG and origin is None:

File "C:\Users\212412120\Downloads\Django-1.7\Django-  1.7\django\conf\__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)

File "C:\Users\212412120\Downloads\Django-1.7\Django-1.7\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting     TEMPLATE_DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the     environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before   accessing settings.
```

I think it has something to do with the environment variables, but I am not sure. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, you have to call settings.configure() it looks like this.

```
import django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
```